# What Data Type is $('#checkbox').attr('checked')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I've done a lot of searching on the web and found examples that treat `$('#checkbox').attr('checked')` as a string and others that treat it as a Boolean.

In my case, I find that this statement works as expected:

```
$('#AcceptAgreement').attr('checked', false);
```

But this one does not:

```
if ($('#AcceptAgreement').attr('checked') == true)
```

The second statement is false because in fact the value is 'checked'.

So which is it? Is it a string or Boolean value, and how can I read and write it in a reliable manner?

Comment: `you almost always want the prop() method and not the attr() method. prop() accepts only a boolean, attr accepts both, but can be slower, or might not be the proper way of accessing the property of an element.`

Comment: Maybe it is dated back to time when IE allowed checkboxes with `checked='1'`, `disabled='true'` but may not on some other browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on which version of jQuery you are using.

`checked` is both a property and an attribute. In older versions of jQuery, `.attr()` always returned the property, not the attribute, which was usually a boolean value. Newer versions of jquery (1.6+) have a new method called `.prop` which returns the boolean property value, while `.attr()` now properly returns the string value. I'm not sure if the attribute is always updated when the property changes.

Comment: Sounds right. Looks like I have 1.7.1. Seems to be working reliably so far.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you should not use attributes, to change state just use 'checked' property of the dom node

```
$('#AcceptAgreement')[0].checked = false
if ($('#AcceptAgreement')[0].checked)
```

Comment: +1. No "probably" about it. This is definitely the most sensible and reliable option.

Answer (score 1):

It's a string, but jQuery lets you set it with a boolean value, which then changes the attribute accordingly. Setting it to "false" results in `attr('checked')` returning `undefined`.

Comment: Did the designers of jQuery assume I'd only want to set it but not read it?

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: I can't see into their minds. I just know what they did. :P

Comment: @JonathanWood it made since prior to the addition of the `.prop` method when `.attr` actually did return a boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental way of finding out the data types

```
console.log(typeof $('#AcceptAgreement').attr('checked'));
```

But before jQuery 1.7, it used to return property value, now it returns pure string.

Another alternative to this is `.prop('checked')` which return boolean.

Answer (score 0):

To write you must use:

```
$('#AcceptAgreement').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

If you wanna know if it is checked can use:

```
if($('#AcceptAgreement').attr('checked'))
```

Comment: But your first snippet also works the way I did it, and the second snippet causes the problems I described in my question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
if ($('#AcceptAgreement').is(':checked'))
{
   //...
}
```

or shortend:

```
$('#isAgeSelected').is(':checked') ? /*true*/ : /*false*/ ;
```